# Twig count the number of items according to a name

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a residence table with a relationship ManyToOne residence -> requests. I would like to count the number of applications from each residence. I already start by displaying my 2 residences but I would like to count the number of applications for each residence. Here is my code.

```
{% set countD = [] %}
{% for key in demandes|keys %}
  {% if demandes[key].residence.name not in countD %}
    Résidence : <em style="color:#b94a83;">{{ demandes[key].residence.name }}</em>
    <br/>
    {% set countD = countD|merge([demandes[key].residence.name]) %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Should be handled in your controller, not your template

Comment: @DarkBee, or even in a TwigExtension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of logic should be implemented in your controller, otherwise can do using this:

```
{% set residences = [] %}
{% set demandesCount = {} %}
{% for key in demandes|keys %}
    {% set name =  demandes[key].residence.name %}
    {% set demandesCount = demandesCount|merge({ (name) : demandesCount[name]|default(0) + 1 }) %}
    {% if name not in residences %}
        Résidence : <em style="color:#b94a83;">{{ name }}</em>
        <br/>
        {% set residences = residences|merge([(name)]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**demandesCount** will have something like this

[image]

Then use this array when you need.

If you need display the amount of demands when print the residence name then a little change is required:

```
{% set residences = [] %}
{% set demandesCount = {} %}
{% for key in demandes|keys %}
    {% set name =  demandes[key].residence.name %}
    {% set demandesCount = demandesCount|merge({ (name) : demandesCount[name]|default(0) + 1 }) %}
    {% set residences = residences|merge({(name) : name}) %}
{% endfor %}

{% for name in residences %}
    Résidence : <em style="color:#b94a83;">{{ name }}</em> ({{ demandesCount[name] }})
    <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Due to the complexity of the template is advised do this type of logic in the controller, but sometimes is needed ;)